# NuxtJS show alternative Navbar at specific scroll Position doesn`t work

Tags: javascript, html, nuxt.js, addeventlistener

I am currently working on a **NuxtJS** project, where I want to **show** an **alternative**, smaller **Navbar** **when scrolled down** till the main Navbar isn`t shown anymore.

Therefor I am currently using the following Code

```
  mounted () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
      this.scrollPos = window.scrollY

      if (this.scrollPos >= 207) {
        this.showAltNavbar = true
      }
    })
  },
```

```
<template>
  <div>
    <navbar-main />
    <navbar-sub />
    <navbar-alt v-show="showAltNavbar" />
    <nuxt />
    <the-footer />
  </div>
</template>
```

The problem that I am facing now is, that the variable showAltNavbar does not change its value and therefor the alternative Navbar is not visible at all times.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or is there already a fancy much better solution out there?

Comment: Some browsers don't support `window.scrollY` what browser are you using and can you console.log(window.scrollY) in your mounted and see if anything gets printed on scroll?

Comment: @S.Ramjit Thanks for your response.

Yes I already tried `window.scrollY` with a console.log inside the mounted hook and it works as expected. The if statement inside the mounted hook as shown above also works.

I tested this with Google Chrome

Comment: Yes my `data()` property looks like this.

data () {
    return {
      scrollPos: 0,
      showAltNavbar: false
    }
  },

Comment: I'm not sure what's the issue, hopefully someone else can help out. Only thing I can say is try `v-if` or set `showAltNavbar` to `true` by default and see if it shows up then.